# MvvmCross: Using custom MvxAdapter from fragments

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to add a header and footer to an `MvxListView` by using my own custom `MvxAdapter`.

From an Activity, I can just add the adapter to the listview in the `OnCreate()` method, and it just works.

But if I try to do the same from the `OnCreateView()` in a Fragment I get a `Java.Lang.RuntimeException` with the following stack trace:

```
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/390?source=cc

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron. Seems the fix was to create a custom `MvxListView` and set the custom `MvxsAdapter` in the base constructor.